# How to display a list on the button when hovering over button

Tags: list, button, hover

I have a button and I want to make a name of the button disapear when you hover over it. At the same time I want the background to change and show a list on the button.

```
    .buttons{
            width: auto;
            position:horizontal;
            font-size: 0;
            background-color: darkslategrey;
            border-radius: 10px;
            }

        .buttons .btn-1{
            display:inline-block ;
            border-radius: 8px;
            background-image: url("/img/teatritood.JPG");
            cursor: pointer;
            background-size: 100%;
            border: none;
            padding:none;
            height: 30rem;
            width: 33.3%;
            font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
            color: whitesmoke;
            font-display: bold;
            font-size: 30px;
            box-shadow: inset 80px 80px 80px darkslategrey, inset -80px -80px 80px darkslategrey;
        }

        .btn-1:hover{

            background-image: url("/img/teatritood.JPG");
            cursor: pointer;
            transition-duration: 0s;
            background-size: 100%;
            border: none;
            padding:none;
            width: 30.33%;
            height: 30rem;
            font-size: 0px;
            box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 10px darkslategrey, inset -10px -10px 10px darkslategrey; 
            }

        .btn-1:hover::after{

            display: block;
            content: attr(data-hover);
            font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
            color: whitesmoke;
            font-display: bold;
            font-size: 38px;
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
```

```
<pre>
    <section>
        <div class="buttons">
            <div>
                <button type="button" class=btn-1 data-hover="Uus list">Teatritööd</button>
                <button type="button" class=btn-2 data-hover="Uus list">Näitused</button>
                <button type="button" class=btn-3 data-hover="Uus list">Muud</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
        <div class="hidden-list">
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <ul><a>Projektid</a></ul>
                    <ul>Kirjeldused</ul>
                    <ul>Pildid</ul>
                </ul>
             </div>
         </div>
    </pre>
```